# Swift change the position of a button

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

In the following piece of code I try to move a button and update the score label.
When I move the button the button moves exactly as I intended, but when I update the label as well the button just stays on the same coordinates.
In the piece of code below everything works great.

```
@IBAction func clickButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    if inGame == false {

        segmentedControl.isHidden = true
        inGame = true
        score = 0

    } else {

        clickButton.isHidden = true
        let height = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(screenHeight))
        let width = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(screenWidth))
        clickButton.center.x = CGFloat(width)
        clickButton.center.y = CGFloat(height)

        score += 1

        clickButton.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

But when I add this below `score += 1` the button does not move anymore.

```
scoreDisplay.text = String(score)
```

How can I get the button to move and get to `scoreDisplay` updated?

Comment: What is the relationship between `scoreDisplay` and `clickButton`? Does your app crash?

Comment: your content is within UIscrollview? and you want to move at bottom content like that?

Comment: Thanks luk2302,
There is no relation at all, the only thing is when I tap the click button the click button should be moved and the score label should update every time I tap the click button.

Comment: AtulParmar,
I don't know what you mean, all the code is in the viewController